# MATLAB - vectorize iteration over two matrices used in function

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have two matrices `X and Y`, both of order `mxn`. I want to create a new matrix `Z` of order `mx1` such that each `i th` entry in this new matrix is computed by applying a function to `ith` and `ith` row of `X` and `Y` respectively. In my case m = 100000 and n = 2. I tried using a loop but it takes forever.

```
for i = 1:m
    Z = function(X(1,:),Y(1,:), constant_parameters)
end
```

Is there an efficient way to vectorize it?

**EDIT 1**

This is the function

```
function [peso] = fxPesoTexturaCN(a,b, img, r, L)

    ac = num2cell(a);
    bc = num2cell(b);

    imgint1 = img(sub2ind(size(img),ac{:})); 
    imgint2 = img(sub2ind(size(img),bc{:}));

    peso =  (sum((a - b) .^ 2) + (r/L) * (imgint2 - imgint1)) / (2*r^2);
```

Where `img, r, L` are constats. `a is X(1,:)` and `b is Y(1,:)`

And the call of this function is

```
peso = bsxfun(@(a,b) fxPesoTexturaCN(a,b,img,r,L), a, b);
```

Comment: Did you pre-allocate `Z`? That would increase the speed a little. How complicated is your `function`? Can you include it in your question?

Comment: *Is there an efficient way to vectorize it?* Not without knowing the function.

Comment: @eigenchris even pre-allocating I don't know how to take down the for-loop. I woul like to vectorize it

Comment: You are converting to cell with `num2cell` and then unpacking back with `{:}`? That didn't make sense to me. Also, you said `img` is a constant and then you are doing `size(img)`? That too got me confused.

Comment: @Divakar you are right!. I am using num2cell because the function must only receive row vectors, but the function call is from bsxfun. Is for that reason that I need a loop to pass row vectors, I would like to avoid this loop by calling the function in a vectorized way